# where is this method doing in admin controller (Grid Serializer)?

Tags: magento

```
    <?php

class Excellence_Manager_Adminhtml_ManagerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

    public function customerAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer.grid')
        ->setCustomers($this->getRequest()->getPost('customers', null));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

I am following [this](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid?facebook=1) grid serializer tute . I just can not understand where is this setCustomers coming from ?

Even in other tutes I saw that setClent(), setDog() etc. But where is get or it's not from the database either. not in the layout either I think. Please help thanks.

```
    <manager_adminhtml_manager_customer>
   <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
       <block type="manager/adminhtml_manager_edit_tab_grid" name="customer.grid"/>
       <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="grid_serializer">
           <reference name="grid_serializer">
               <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                   <grid_block_name>customer.grid</grid_block_name>
                   <data_callback>getSelectedCustomers</data_callback>
                   <hidden_input_name>links[customers]</hidden_input_name>
                   <reload_param_name>customers</reload_param_name>
               </action>
               <action method="addColumnInputName">
                   <input_name>position</input_name>
               </action>
           </reference>
       </block>
   </block>
```

I found it's not from hidden_input_name or reload_param_name.

Answer (score 0):

```
__set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.

__get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.
```

Magento implements so called "Magic Methods" to set data in an object.
They implemented `__set` and `__get` which are called, when no method for e.g. setCustomers() is found, and use those methods to do `setData('customers', "YOUR_VALUE");`